# alert message not working properly in Ajax web method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Always getting the 'save error' message when I call the Ajax web method.But I can save the data to database.I couldn't find any errors.How can I get alert 'Saved' .
my web method is

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "paygrade.aspx/SavePayGrade",
            data: JSON.stringify({ value: rec, arr: arr }),
            success: function (msg) {
                console.log(msg.d);
                alert(msg.d);

            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("Save error");
            }
        });



 [WebMethod]
  public static string SavePayGrade(string value, params string[] arr)
    {
        string res = "";
        using (FlairEntities context = new FlairEntities())
        {

            tblPayGrade obj = new tblPayGrade();

                obj.salaryGrade = arr[0];
                obj.salary = arr[1];
                obj.note = arr[2];

                context.tblPayGrades.Add(obj);
                context.SaveChanges();
                res = "Saved";

        }

        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Can you console.log 'msg' in the error method and see what the details are? Or check your response via debugger network tab to get more details on the error?

Comment: is it the webmethod is called properly ? did u check it with a breakpoint ?

Comment: what is the values of rec and arr on client side?

Comment: Instead of alert("Save error");
Check with alert(msg);

Comment: What is msg.d in success alert?

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
console.log(msg);

alert(msg);
```

As you are sending response in string( **return res;**), you cant use **msg.d** 
You need to use only **msg**.